# QuickSort is returning correct values, but not sorting in place

Tags: python, quicksort

I'm struggling to understand why my QuickSort *returns* the sorted values correctly, but the resulting array is not sorted correctly.

```
def qSort(array):
    n = len(array)
    if (n == 1 or n ==0):
            return array
    p_index = partition(array)
    p_value = array[p_index]
    return(qSort(array[0:p_index]) + [p_value] + qSort(array[p_index+1:n]))

def partition(array):
    pivot = array[0]
    i = 1
    for j in xrange(1,len(array)):
        print j
        if array[j] < pivot:
            tmp = array[j]
            array[j] = array[i]
            array[i]=tmp
            i += 1
    tmp = array[i-1]
    array[i-1] = pivot
    array[0] = tmp
    return i-1
```

Here is some sample output:

```
>>> q = [5,4,3,2,1]
>>> qSort(q)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> q
[1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are making up a new list in your `return` statement.

```
return(qSort(array[0:p_index]) + [p_value] + qSort(array[p_index+1:n]))
```

If the `qSort` function reaches a base case, it returns a list, which is concatenated with `[p_value]` and returned as a `list`. You do not make changes to the passed in `list` anywhere.

When you call your `qSort` function recursively, you are giving it a slice of the list and the function returns the list in the base case which you then append to the `pivot` and the other recursive call, hence generating a new list.

See what is happening by changing your `qSort` function to

```
def qSort(array):
    n = len(array)
    if (n == 1 or n ==0):
            return array
    p_index, array = partition(array)
    p_value = array[p_index]
    returnVal = qSort(array[0:p_index]) + [p_value] + qSort(array[p_index+1:n])
    print "Returning:", returnVal, "Original Array:", array
    return returnVal
```

Output -

```
>>> q = [5,4,3,2,1]
>>> qSort(q)
Returning: [2, 3] Original Array: [2, 3]
Returning: [2, 3, 4] Original Array: [2, 3, 4]
Returning: [1, 2, 3, 4] Original Array: [1, 4, 3, 2]
Returning: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] Original Array: [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To reflect the changes in your original `list`, you have the option of doing `q = qSort(q)`.

**P.S** - Setting up a random index instead of the first value would be better for your quicksort function. See the bit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) on `Choice of Pivots`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work `q = qSort(array[0:p_index]) + [p_value] + qSort(array[p_index+1:n])`
`return(q)`

Comment: You're still making up a new list. If you need to sort your list in-place, you need to make changes to it in the code, or do `q = qSort(q)`.

Comment: @tonydx : You need to do `q = qSort(q)` in IDLE.

Comment: Thank you, your feedback is very helpful–where is my code incorrect for sorting in place though? That's what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Hi! You should refer to @Lee Daniel Crocker 's answer in that case, you basically have to set up low and high bounds (instead of slicing the array) and then operate on the list within those bounds.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, slicing and combining lists create new lists. If you want your recursive calls to operate on a single list in place, pass the list and the bounds into the call, and don't return anything from the function. Something like:

```
def qsort(array, low, high):
    if high-low < 2:
        return

    # Choose pivot, do partition within bounds

    if partition > low:
        qsort(array, low, partition)
    if partition < high:
        qsort(array, partition+1, high)
```

Then just call `qsort(a, 0, len(a))` to sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

apply the function back to q

q = qSort(q)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the array and also sort in place you should before returning make the array equal to the result and not make a new one. You can do that by changing your return statement to:

```
    array[:] = qSort(array[0:p_index]) + [p_value] + qSort(array[p_index+1:n])
    return array
```

Note that

```
    array = qSort(array[0:p_index]) + [p_value] + qSort(array[p_index+1:n])
```

does not work either, because the lhs variable will be treated as a local variable.